# iOS VoIP application detect connection drop

Tags: ios, voip

I'm building a VoIP-like which connects to a server which is not very stable (please don't tell me to fix the server, its not mine). I'm expected to write an iOS app which connects to this server, and if the connection breaks, inform the user. I can do this in foreground mode very easily.

How do I do this in background mode. setKeepAliveTimeout is called only once every 10 mins. I need to alert the user that connection is broken immediately. Is there some notification I can register for which tells me if the connection to a server is broken, in background mode?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

As I konw, maybe you can solved the issue like this.

when you go into the background mode.iOS will stop execute your code.So you can not do it by your own code.

But iOS will wake up your code for a little while if you set the socket to be voip when the socket receive data in the socket.So you can let your server send you some data to wake your app,like every 10 seconds.

It may work.But I have not tried.